# How to solve this print output in C++

Tags: c++

I had the below C++ question in the recent interview but could not do. Please help.

Given a company structure where every employee reports to a superior, all the way up to the CEO, how would you print out all the employees that a particular individual oversees?

Write a method that implements this, given the below:

```
// Employee object contains a string denoting the. 
// employee name, and an array containing 
// employees who report to this employee

 Employee {
 String name;
 Employee[] employees;
 }
```

I have seen and understand the recursive function. But I have not encounter such a recursive object/structure like this one.

My new question is how can an object is created and initialized from this class/structure since it is recursive? 
Thank you very much again.

Comment: You solve this question by trying out various approaches and trying hard. What have you done till now?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you need to read about tree data structures

Comment: Sorry, but before you interview for a position as a programmer, you should at least have understood the fudamental basics. Google for recursion. Though this can be solved without, recursion is the most simple solution. BTW.: I'd have asked how I could know the size of `employees`, since it is an unbound C-legacy array, that does not provide any size information. I'd suggest to use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 3):

With the information given it is very hard to answer (and question should probably be set on hold). Anyway...

I think a recursive approach is the answer. You need a function that can take a name, search the full employee list for that name and then call the function again for every employee in the local array. Something like:

```
void doit(Employee& e)
{
    // Print e.name

    // For each employee tmp in e.employees (i.e. local array)
    doit(tmp);
}
```

Note - this requires that there are no loops in manager-employee arrays. If there is this will be an endless loop. So this is a dangerous approach.

## EDIT:

This is added due to the comment from OP.

As indicated above the question is vague and doesn't really give sufficient information to provide a good answer. The struct given in the question is not valid C++ and there is no description of how the company wide list of employees are maintained.

However to keep it simple, the printing could look like this:

```
struct Employee
{
    void PrintAllReportingEmployee(int level)
    {
        cout << string(4*level, ' ') << name << endl;
        level++;
        for (auto& e : employeesDirectlyReportingToThisEmployee)
        {
            e.PrintAllReportingEmployee(level);
        }
    }

    string name;
    vector<Employee> employeesDirectlyReportingToThisEmployee;
};


// Code in some print function:

// Step 1 - find the relevant employee
Employee tmp = SomeFunctionReturningAnEmployeeBasedOnName("NameOfPerson");

// Step 2 - print all employees reporting directly and indirectly
tmp.PrintAllReportingEmployee(0);
```

This assumes a single top-level Employee (e.g. director) with a vector of employees directly reporting to the director. Each of these would then have a vector of employees reporting to them and so. So it is kind of an tree structure.

Note, if I should design a employee db, I would not go with such a solution.

Comment: I am a junior programmer.  I do not know how to solve this problem using c++. Please help me out so that I can learn how the function would be written for this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Who ever asked the question was looking for an answer with something to do with class inheritance.  So a class Persion is extended by Employee where Person is also extended by Manager etc etc where they all share some similar properties but not everything.

This means that your code can be expanded upon by other programmers and one change can fix many different classes!

Although this code does not demonstrate class inheritance, it will work.

```
 /*
    THE OUTPUT:

    Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:~ jacob$ ./employee
    Foo McGoo
    Bar Too
    Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:~ jacob$ 
    */

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using std::string;
    using std::vector;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    /* define class (this should be in a header file) */
    class Employee{
    public:
        //Variables
        string Name;
        //Functions
        Employee(const string&); //constructor
        void AddCoWorker(const Employee&);
        void ShowCoWorkers();
    private:
        vector<Employee> employees;
    }; //Note the semicolon

    //Entry point
    int main(int argc, char **argv){
        Employee foo("Foo McGoo");
        Employee bar("Bar Too");
        Employee me("Bevis");

        me.AddCoWorker(foo);
        me.AddCoWorker(bar);
        me.ShowCoWorkers();
    return 0;
    }

    //Class functions (should be in a separate cpp file)
    Employee::Employee(const string& name){
        this->Name = name;
    }

    void Employee::AddCoWorker(const Employee &e){
        this->employees.push_back(e);
    }

    void Employee::ShowCoWorkers(){
        int count = this->employees.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            //Print the names of each co worker on separate lines
            cout << this->employees[i].Name << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to write the function but it did not work. I am stuck.Could anyone help out so that I could learn what

Comment: @user5693731there ya go.  read carefully and once you understand that you should begin to learn about why the keyword const appears as the arguments and how the C++ compiler conventions do things like automatically call constructors to create copies of objects and how references and pointers allow flexibility with data

Comment: Nothing in the question indicates that you are supposed to write your own class or that this has to do anything with inheritance (which your solution doesn't do anyway) and finally, your solution doesn't recurse down the hierarchy.

Comment: It can't hurt to help someone understand.  Thanks for reading part of my answer back to me  by the way.  That took only two minutes to write probably less time it took for you to write that remark.

Comment: So what? I can write a Hello world program in just a few seconds and talk about the advantages of templates. That also would not be an answer to the question. My comment wasn't about a missing detail in your answer or that the code could be optimized somehow, but about it failing to address the actual problem (printing all members of a tree).

Comment: I have seen and understood how the recursive function works. But I have not encountered such a recursive object/structure like this one.

My new question to all: How can an object is created and initialized from this class/structure since it is recursive? Thank you very much again.